# Optional value?

Tags: ios, swift

I wrote this code:

```
mapView.setRegion(
     MKCoordinateRegion(
         center: CLLocationCoordinate2DMake(location.coordinate.latitude, location.coordinate.longitude), 
         span: MKCoordinateSpanMake(0.05, 0.05)
     ), 
     animated: true
)
```

I am getting the EXC_Breakpoint error and it also says unexpecdaly found nil while unwrapping an optional value.

Comment: Probably because `location.coordinate` is nil. However you are obtaining `location`, it is not baked yet.

Answer (score 0):

Welcome to Stack Overflow.

You need to break your code into the smallest parts you can and see where the problem is coming from.

Log "location" and see if it's nil, or set a breakpoint and examine it in the debugger.

Then create your MKCoordinateRegion in a separate variable and make sure that's not returning nil:

```
println("location = \(location)")
let coordinate = CLLocationCoordinate2DMake(
  location.coordinate.latitude, 
  location.coordinate.longitude)
let span = MKCoordinateSpanMake(0.05, 0.05)

let region = MKCoordinateRegion(center: coordinate, span: span)
println("region = \(region)")

mapView.setRegion(region, animated: true)
```

My money is on location being nil.

Comment: @Duncan_C I broke it up and it is coming from the mapView.setRegion . Theres also two other places where the code says the same error:       completionHandler?(latitude: latitude, longitude: longitude, status: locationStatus, verboseMessage:verbose, error: nil)   and              self.displayLocation(CLLocation(latitude: latitude, longitude: longitude))
Thank you so much

Comment: What do you see if you add the println statements I show above?

Comment: @Duncan_C Nothing. It just keeps going back to that error right away without letting you touch anything in the app. Could it be the "Can we use your location" message in the info.pilst?

Comment: "It just keeps going back to that error right away without letting you touch anything in the app." I have no idea what you mean by that.  'Could it be the "Can we use your location" message in the info.pilst?' Certainly. You need to have the properties in your plist, and do a series of calls to ask permission to use the location manager, and fail gracefully if permission is denied. You didn't include any of that information in your question though

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem doing the same code and the problem was because I didn't connect my mapView and my label to my controller :/

I realized that when I saw my outlets empty

[image]